# PHP - How to see if a word is on a specific webpage?

Tags: php, string, search, substring, file-get-contents

I need to check if a webpage outside of my site has a specific word on it. I’ve tried file_get_contents() but it doesn’t return anything. Is there any way I can do this in PHP?

edit: Here’s what I’ve tried:

```
$query = 'example';
$file = "https:// www.site.com/search?q=$query";
// tested url and it works, had to add space to post it
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
echo $contents;
```

I was expecting it to just output the entire page for me to use `.includes()` on later but it just doesn’t output anything.

Comment: what exactly have you tried, show us your best attempt so we can help you.

Comment: i edited the post with my changes

Comment: Sorry I’m kinda novice at PHP and haven’t had to include one before. Which one works here and how do I implement it? Thanks

Comment: oh i thought you meant like GET or POST etc. I’m using https, ill change it

Comment: Can you CURL the request from command line? If not the site may block requests without a valid user agent.

Comment: let the one line look like `$file = "https://www.example.com/search?q=" . urlencode($query);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into `curl` to get the contents of a web page. Then you can use `preg_match` to find the word.